# Will having reversed hot and cold damage my faucet?

Tags: kitchens, taps

On our old kitchen tap handles, the cold is on the left side and hot on the right. The new taps are the exact opposite, cold being on the right and hot on the left side. Is it okay to just connect them as they are as long as we, obviously, remember what side the cold and hot are on? Can it ruin anything like the cold water hose/pipes, etc.?

Comment: Unless the faucet has a thermostatic temperature control device, it doesn't physically matter which side carries hot water, the same materials are used on both sides.

Answer (score 3):

This is an easy fix. Your supply lines were simply installed to the wrong shutoff.

If you look under your sink there should be two shutoff valves. One hot, one cold. The supply lines (may be rubber or have a stainless sheath or plastic) go from these valves to your faucet.

Turn the shutoffs off. Open both sides of the faucet to relieve pressure. Unhook the lines at the shutoff and put them on the opposite shutoff. Turn the shutoffs back on. You should now have cold on the right and hot on the left.

This is such a simple repair there is no reason to "just live with it" and as @Steven states it could be a minor hazard for guests.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest risk is someone being burned.  In North America, cold should always be on the right side and hot on the left.  If you are outside of this region you should check with local standards.

It sounds like you either bought a faucet from a different region, or maybe your original faucet was installed backwards.

With regards to the actual plumbing, it shouldn't make a difference which side you are hooked up to.

Comment: I'm not sure what would be more confusing: to have the faucets labeled wrong but be on the correct side conventionally, or to be labeled correctly but on the wrong side conventionally. If the left/right side is a regional convention then I would strongly suggest getting a locally-appropriate faucet. Depending on how hot your water is, burns from a faucet could be severe.

Comment: Not only is it usually simple to switch the supply if that's what's reversed, it's also often possible to easily reverse the labels if that's what's wrong. Single lever faucets may have replacement handles with regionally appropriate labels.

Comment: @HenryJackson Funny! I just lived 9 months with my kitchen faucet labeled backwards (it said that pulling the joystick to the left would be cold but was actually hot), and we just switched the hoses yesterday, and I'm now thinking it was better to have the incorrect label than to buck North American convention and habit. It feels weird to have "hot" on the right. Obviously, if I could figure out an easy enough way to correct the blue and red dots built into the joystick, I'd switch the hoses back. And I might switch the hoses back *anyway*.